# Find the closest previous DateTime from a list of DateTime

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

Is there a faster way of obtaining the closest previous (past) DateTime from a list of DateTimes when compared to a specific time? (the list comes from a SQL database)

```
public DateTime GetClosestPreviousDateTime(List<DateTime> dateTimes, DateTime specificTime)
{
    DateTime ret = null;
    var lowestDifference = TimeSpan.MaxValue;

    foreach (var date in dateTimes)
    {
        if (date >= specificTime)
            continue;

        var difference = specificTime- date;

        if (difference < lowestDifference)
        {
            lowestDifference = difference;
            ret = date;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

The source list will be sorted since the dates in the list come from a SQL database where they are written consecutively.

Comment: What is `target` in your code.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that when I pasted it here from my original code. It should have been 'specificTime'

Comment: In the first line, you cannot assign `null` to a `DateTime` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "faster". The algorithm you show is O(N) so no you won't get faster than that - if by faster you mean is there a way to not have to iterate over all dates.

But if you mean can you shave off a few microseconds with some code that doesn't emit quite as many op codes, then yes of course. But is that really the issue here?

The answer will also change based on the size of the list, how accurate you need the answer to be, whether we can make any assumptions on the data (e.g. is it already sorted).

Comment: The list is sorted, as in the dates are written consecutively in the database

Comment: Well that makes a big difference. You start from the latest date (which presumably could be in the future) and stop as soon as you find a date in the past. Then you may not have to always iterate over all dates. All you need to know is the order they are sorted (ascending or descending) and take it from there. You may be faster to start from the earliest date and move forward, it depends if you know generally whether most dates are in the past or the future.

Comment: If the list is sorted, then simple binary search for `specificTime` will give the desired result in O(Log(N))

Comment: Even better. If you're querying the database - why not just put the condition in your query that you don't want any dates ahead of specificTime, and then take the first or last element from the result (depending on if you sort ASC or DESC).

Answer (score 0):

```
dateTimes.Where(x => x < specificTime).Max()
```

or if you want to handle the case where none exist:

```
dateTimes.Where(x => x < specificTime).DefaultIfEmpty().Max()
```

---

Later edit: Now you introduce new information that the `List<>` is already sorted. That was not in the question before.

With a sorted `List<>`, your algorithm is silly since it `foreach`es on and on, even after having reached the point where the entries "pass" the threshold `specificTime`. You can use instead `BinarySearch` (assuming `List<>` is sorted in *ascending* order *and contains no duplicates*):

```
static DateTime GetClosestPreviousDateTime(List<DateTime> dateTimes, DateTime specificTime)
{
  var search = dateTimes.BinarySearch(specificTime);
  var index = (search < 0 ? ~search : search) - 1;
  if (index == -1)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Not found");
  return dateTimes[index];
}
```

If you want to do it faster, just ask the database for the value, it will know how to find the answer fast; do not fetch the entire `List<>` to memory first. Use SQL or LINQ to the database.

Comment: In what way would this be faster?

Comment: It's faster to type.

Comment: I can see that this would only enumerate and compare the DateTimes that are less than the DateTime in question. Given that my method skips all those DateTimes that are in future, how would this method be faster performance-wise?

Comment: When you use Linq, you are delegating to the runtime, which presumably knows the current conditions and can execute the best algorithm in the best way possible, at least in theory.

Comment: @astralmaster Your method with `lowestDifference` and so on makes no sense for an already sorted `List<>`. I edited my answer.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen My specific list might be sorted, but that's not always the case

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a classic search algorithm and binary search might suit you.

1. Sort list: `dateTimes.Sort();`
2. Apply Binary Search algo with similar logic as in your for statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
dateTimes.Sort();
var closest = dateTimes[dateTimes.IndexOf(search) - 1];
```

Comment: This will be slower. All sort algorithms are slower than a single pass over the dataset.